# Proving $\nabla_X (\text{tr}\ F) = \text{tr} (\nabla_XF)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, tensor-products

Let $F\in\mathcal T^{k}_{l}(M)$ be a smooth section of a $(k,l)$-tensor bundle over the manifold $M$. The trace operator
$$
\text{tr}:\mathcal T^{k}_{l}(M) \to\mathcal T^{k-1}_{l-1}(M)
$$
is defined by
$$
(\text{tr}\ F)(\omega^1,\dots,\omega^{l-1},Y_1,\dots,Y_{k-1}):=\text{tr}\left( F(\omega^1,\dots,\omega^{l-1},\omega,Y_1,\dots,Y_{k-1},Y) \right)
$$
where trace on the RHS is the regular trace of the $(1,1)$-tensor in variables $\omega$ and $Y$.

> How do I show that $$\nabla_X (\text{tr} F) =  \text{tr} (\nabla_XF)$$
>   holds?

Writing it out in coordinate seems like a real pain, is there a nicer way to prove this? I tried to do it in local coordinate and it looks quite messy.

**EDIT:** The definition I am using is the computational one, i.e
$$\begin{align}
\nabla_X F(\omega^1,\dots,\omega^l,Y_1,\dots,Y_k):&=XF(\omega^1,\dots,Y_k)\\&-F(\nabla_X\omega^1,\omega^2,\dots,Y_k)-\dots -F(\omega^1,\dots,Y_{k-1},\nabla_X Y_k)
\end{align}$$

Comment: What is your definition of $\nabla$ on tensors? The definition I am used to includes this property (commuting with contractions) as an axiom.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I've edited the question to add that. This is a part of the proof that $\nabla_X$ on tensor bundles is uniquely determined by the affine connection on $M$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** It is known that $\nabla_XF$ is a tensor (if you haven't already, it may be a good idea to verify that first). This means that the value of $$\nabla_XF\left(\omega^1,\ldots,\omega^l,Y_1,\ldots,Y_k\right)$$at a point $p$ only depends on the values of $\omega^1,\ldots,\omega^l,Y_1,\ldots,Y_k$ at $p$. Consequently, you may assume that $\omega^1,\ldots,\omega^l,Y_1,\ldots,Y_k$ are all parallel in the direction $X$. This will cause most of the terms in your formula vanish and make the computation considerably less messy.

**Edit:** What I meant to say is that, given $\omega^1|_p,\ldots,Y_k|_p,$ we may extend all those vectors and covectors in any way we choose. In particular, we may assume $$\nabla_X\omega^1=\ldots=\nabla_XY_k=0.$$ This would leave us with $$\nabla_XF\left(\omega^1,\ldots,Y_k\right)=X\left(F\left(\omega^1,\ldots,Y_k\right)\right),$$which is much more convenient to work with.

**Edit #$2$:** We wish to show $$\nabla_X\mathrm{tr}F=\mathrm{tr}\nabla_XF.$$This equality holds if and only if it holds at every point, so let $p\in M$, and let $$\omega^1,\ldots,\omega^{l-1}\in T^*_pM,\quad Y_1,\ldots,Y_{k-1}\in T_pM.$$As explained above, we may extend the $\omega$'s and the $Y$'s to global vector fields and $1$-forms in whatever manner we choose; different choices yield different summands in the expression for $\nabla_XF$, but the overall sum remains the same. So we assume $$\nabla_X\omega^1=\ldots=\nabla_XY_{k-1}=0.$$ Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be a local frame of $TM$. Once again, we may assume $$\nabla_Xe_1=\ldots=\nabla_Xe_n=0.$$Let $\varphi^1,\ldots,\varphi^n$ be the dual local frame of $T^*M$. It automatically follows (why??) that $$\nabla_X\varphi^1=\ldots=\nabla_X\varphi^n=0.$$ Finally, due to all our assumptions, $$\begin{align}\nabla_X\mathrm{tr}F\left(\omega^1,\ldots,Y_{k-1}\right)&=X\left(\mathrm{tr}F\left(\omega^1,\ldots,Y_{k-1}\right)\right)\\&=X\left(\sum_iF\left(\omega^1,\ldots,\omega^{l-1},\varphi^i,Y_1,\ldots,Y_{k-1},e_i\right)\right)\\&=\sum_iX\left(F\left(\omega^1,\ldots,\omega^{l-1},\varphi^i,Y_1,\ldots,Y_{k-1},e_i\right)\right)\\&=\sum_i\nabla_XF\left(\omega^1,\ldots,\omega^{l-1},\varphi^i,Y_1,\ldots,Y_{k-1},e_i\right)\\&=\mathrm{tr}\nabla_XF\left(\omega^1,\ldots,Y_{k-1}\right),\end{align}$$as desired.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about assuming that $\omega^1,\ldots,\omega^l,Y_1,\ldots,Y_k$ are all parallel in the direction $X$? I'm not sure what parallel means here.

Comment: I tried what you suggested (if I understand it correctly) and got some leftover terms that I'm not quite sure what to do next. I must admit that I am relatively new to differential geometry and I am not even sure if I calculated the trace correctly. If it's not too long could you please expand your answer a bit more? It'd really help me a lot.

Comment: @BigbearZzz I edited my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: This should make it a lot easier. However, I am still struggling with computing the trace by definition since I've never seen it done before (I never took a diff. geo. course). I may be asking too much but would you mind showing me how it is done properly? Nevertheless, if you don't have the time it is fine, what you wrote already help me a lot. Thanks again!

Comment: @BigbearZzz I added a couple of details.